# How to change an already generated project language from Kotlin to Java in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I created a project using kotlin as the prefer language but for some reasons I want to use java. I don't want to create this project over.

Comment: Pretty sure you can just create and use java files in your project. java and kotlin can be mixed inside a project. I'm not entirely sure but I think there's nothing inherently different in project configurations of an android project in java or kotlin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a file with extension .java and work on that